# sort numbers in php,

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

hi i am using php to learn algorithms, i wanted to convert this psuedocode into php,

```
for i = 1 to n − 1
  minval = A[i]
  minindex = i
    for j = i to n
      if (A[j] < minval)
         minval = A[j]
         minindex = j
       exchange A[i] and A[minindex]
```

this the corresponding code in php

```
$A = array(1, 4, 2, 3, 70, 10, 7 );
    $n = sizeof($A);
    for ($i = 0; $i == $n - 1; $i++){
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j == $n; $j++){
            if ($A[$i] > $A[$j]){
                 $temp = $A[$j];
                $A[$j] = $A[$i];
                $A[$i] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }

print_r($A);
```

print_r is outputting the array as its original order, why my algorithms doents reorder the array ?

Comment: its never going inside `if ($A[$i] > $A[$j]){`. Did you check ?

Comment: Which algorithm are you talking about?!

Comment: @ Pedro Lobito  Bubble Sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your `for`loops :

```
for ($i = 0; $i == $n - 1; $i++){
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j == $n; $j++){
```

should be

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++){
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++){
```

As the second argument in `for` is a requirement to continue the loop.

Comment: thanks dude, hmmm but whats wrong i thought having                                    for( $i = 0; $i == $n; $i++)   means "continue doing the loop until $i equals to $n " am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes you are wrong, it really means "continue *while* $i equals to $n" which is never true so it never enters the loop

Comment: @MohamedKira that is not how for loops work. You can check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) for more information. It really means "do this loop while $I equals $n", but since the first time the loop gets "active" it results to false and will end the loop.

Comment: @MohamedKira Bottom line is, you need to *debug* your code once before post ;) . Hope this helped though.